# Как умножить полученные значения из DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы по взаимодействию с ползунком применялась вот такая формула: первое значение * второе значение = итоговая сумма, а полученные значения выводились в DOM.

value ползунка не должно учитываться в калькуляции

мой неудачный код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#range-yellow').range({
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    start: 200,
    onChange: function(value) {
      $('#display-3').html(value);
      let calc =  oneItem * twoItem
      sumItem.text(calc);
    }
  });
});





let oneItem = $(".range-price-item-1");

let twoItem = $(".range-price-item-2");

let sumItem = (".range-price-item-3");
```

```html
<link href="https://tyleryasaka.github.io/semantic-ui-range/range.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://tyleryasaka.github.io/semantic-ui-range/range.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="range-conin-wrapper">
        <div class="range-coin">
           <div class="range-input">
            <div class="ui yellow range" id="range-yellow">
              <p>
              Value: <span id="display-3">          </span>
          </p>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="range-price">
          <div class="range-price-item">
             <div class="range-price-item-1">
               <h1>Первое значение</h1>
               <p>1</p>
             </div>
            <div class="range-price-item-2">
               <h1>Второе значение</h1>
              <p>2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="range-price-item-3">
              <h1>Итоговая сумма</h1>
              <p>3</p>
            </div>
                   
        </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: извиняюсь. подскажите, пожалуйста,  как  можно  свернуть код?

Comment: @UModeL спасибо большое за рекомендацию. Поправил

Comment: `$('.range-input').on('.range-input', function() {` это что за ивент?

Comment: Где в коде элемент `#range-price-item` ?

Comment: @UModeL а зачем он нужен?

Comment: Нет #energyBill - нечего считать, ну и вы ивенты не выдумывайте

Comment: @InDevX: так он в формуле есть "#savingsCoins * #range-price-item = savingsGains"

Comment: @UModeL а в коде #energyBill вместо него) Да, это сильно

Comment: @InDevX: ага. И затаился... :)

Comment: я что-то напутал. сейчас поправлю код

Comment: @UModeL поправил код и изменил формулировку вопроса

Comment: @kiskiskit: ок, изменили. Но, ползунок не участвует теперь в расчётах?

Comment: значения с ползунка не должны приниматься. ползунок лишь должен запускать умножение

Comment: `oneItem = $(".range-price-item-1")` => `oneItem = +$(".range-price-item-1 p").text()`; `twoItem = $(".range-price-item-2")` => `twoItem = +$(".range-price-item-2 p").text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let oneItem = $(".range-price-item-1 p");
let twoItem = $(".range-price-item-2 p");
let sumItem = $(".range-price-item-3 p");

$('#range-yellow').range({
  min: 100,
  max: 1000,
  start: 200,
  onChange: function(value) {
    $('#display-3').html(value);
    sumItem.text(+oneItem.text() * +twoItem.text() * +value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tyleryasaka.github.io/semantic-ui-range/range.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://tyleryasaka.github.io/semantic-ui-range/range.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="range-input">
  <div class="ui yellow range" id="range-yellow">
    <p>
      Value: <span id="display-3"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="range-price">
  <div class="range-price-item">
    <div class="range-price-item-1">
      <h1>Первое значение</h1>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="range-price-item-2">
      <h1>Второе значение</h1>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="range-price-item-3">
      <h1>Итоговая сумма</h1>
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: допустил оплошность и не подумал откуда брать значение для вычислений. 

Сейчас добавил отслеживание value, но не получается привязать к калькуляции. думаю, что нужно сделать так: значение c value * oneItem * twoItem. 
подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить такую возможность?

мои изменения
 onChange: function(value) {
    
    $('#display-3').html(value);
    sumItem.text(+oneItem.text() * +twoItem.text());
  }

Comment: @kiskiskit: подправил.